# Automapper (v5.1) ConstructedBy replacement?

Tags: automapper, automapper-5

I just upgraded my Automapper from 4.1 to 5.1 and I've found that ConstructedBy doesn't appear to be a valid function anymore.  I read though the help files and it still references ConstructedBy as valid.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
cfg.CreateMap<XElement, Article>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.Publication,
            opt => opt.ResolveUsing<XAttributeResolver<string>>()
                      .ConstructedBy(() => new XAttributeResolver<string>("publication_name", "publication", "publications")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just construct the resolver directly. I removed the redundant configuration in favor of an overload:

```
cfg.CreateMap<XElement, Article>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Publication,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new XAttributeResolver<string>("publication_name", "publication", "publications")));
```